# How to read Cookie from Controller in seperate assembly in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

In my project Controllers are in seperate assembly and Viwes in seperate, now i need to read browser cookie into the Controller and while i am reading it using 
HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["_sometext"].Value, i am geeting the null.
i think this becz controller in seperate assembly.

so how to read browser cookie into the Controoler which is in sepearte assembly?

Answer (score 0):

You can access your cookies form your controller with this line of code.

```
Request.Cookies["your_cookie_name"]
```